# Prove the set ${\{u \in \mathbb{R^n} | f(u)<c}\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, examples-counterexamples

The following is from the book Advanced Calculus by P.M.Fitzpatrick:

[image]

Considering the first case of 4 cases in the Corollary, the two sets ${\{u \in \mathbb{R^n} | f(u)<c}\}$ and ${\{v \in \mathbb{R} | v<c}\}$ are not 'same'. That is the set ${\{v \in \mathbb{R} | v<c}\}$ is an open set but the set ${\{u \in \mathbb{R^n} | f(u)<c}\}$ may not be an open set (it may not be an interval) depending on the defined function $f$.

For example consider ${\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} | x^2/5+y^2/4<1}\}$ is an open set but $x^2/5+y^2/4<1$ is actually $0\le x^2/5+y^2/4 < 1$. It is a lame example (at least the mentioned Corollary is not useful for this example) but

My question are : **1.** Is there exist some fuction $f$ such that $f(u)<c$ to mean $a\le f(u) \le b <c$ becasue of range of the $f$?

And, **2.** how ${\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2} | x^2/5+y^2/4<1}\}$ is an open set but $0\le x^2/5+y^2/4 < 1$ is not open in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of a continuous function is one for which preimages of open sets are open. The set $\{u\in\mathbb{R}^n|f(u)<c\}$ is the preimage under $f$ of the set $\{v\in\mathbb{R}|v<c\}$, so it must be open by definition of continuity.

If you're working with a different definition of continuity, then you can mimic part of the proof that the definitions are equivalent. To show that preimages of open sets are open, you need to pick a point in the preimage and show that there is some $\delta$-neighborhood around it that is also in the preimage, but that's precisely what the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity states, once we know that the image is open.

---

Following the edit of your question, it is certainly the case that the preimage of an open set may also be described as the preimage of some non-open set, but that doesn't harm anything. A simple example, using a function from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is this: We can describe $\{x|x^2<1\}$ equally well as $\{x|0\leq x^2<1\}$. Either way, its preimage is the open interval $(-1,1)$.

Additionally: $\{x|-2<\sin x<2\}=\{x|-2\leq\sin x\leq 2\}=\{x|\sin x<2\}$.

Why isn't this a problem? Well, the definition of continuity doesn't say that open sets are preimages *only* of open sets. It also doesn't say that forward images of open sets must be open. All that is required is IF $C$ is open in the codomain, THEN $f^{-1}(C)$ is open in the domain. That remains true, even if the image of $f$ occupies some part of $C$ that is not, itself, open.

It still won't be the case that an open set (that is not also closed) would be a preimage of a *closed* set, because an alternative characterization of continuity is that preimages of closed sets are closed.

Answer (score 0):

If $f:X\to Y$ is continuous, then for each open set $B\subset Y$ holds $f^{-1}(B)$ is open in $X$.

Now you have $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ and you consider $B=\{v\in \mathbb R~:~v<c\}$ which is open in $\mathbb R$. Hence
$$f^{-1}(B)=\{v\in\mathbb R^n~:~f(v)\in B\}=\{v\in\mathbb R^n~:~f(v)<c\}$$
is open in $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding.  We first recall that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ is open if and only if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any open set in $\mathbb{R}$. If we set $U=\{v\in \mathbb{R}; v<c\}$, then $f^{-1}(U)=\{{\bf u}\in \mathbb{R}^n; f({\bf u})<c\}$. That is why the argument says that the set f^{-1}(U)={{\bf u}\in \mathbb{R}^n; f({\bf u})